# Get variables from ajax request in code behind

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core-2.0

So, some time ago, I needed to make ajax requests to access the code behind. I did that ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45421875/call-c-sharp-function-on-code-behind-from-ajax-function)).

But now I'm working on asp.NET Core 2.0 and it works differently. Well, now I can make a request but, for some reason The variables are null (only on the code behind, on the client side they have content. Probably isn't a big deal, but I can't grasp why.

So, here's my ajax function:

```
function Ajax(expression1, expression2, url, json, error) {
            console.log(expression1+" - "+ expression2);
            var request = { email: expression1, password: expression2 }

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: 'post',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(request),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (resp) {
            console.log(request);
            if (expression1 === null || expression2===null)
                window.location.href = resp[json];
            else
                document.getElementById(error).innerHTML = resp[json];
        },
        error: function (error) {
        }
    })
}
```

And the c# code:

```
public string ExternalLogin(string email, string name)
        {
            //TODO: Facebook login

            // Redirect link example. Could be another one.
            return "{\"facebook\":\"Home/About\"}";
        }
```

The ajax function makes the request and it triggers the c# function, and returns what I ask it to. The only problem is the null variables. Why is this happening?

EDIT: The User class as requested:

```
public class User
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName ="email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter binding fails because you are making a post request here.
You have to add the `[FromBody]` attribute to your parameters.

You can get more info about paramter binding here:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

EDIT:

You also passing a object as paramter so you either have to change you route paramter to an object containing email and password property, or you change your Content-Type to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' and pass a query string like 'email=....&password=....'

Comment: Just that? I've added the [FromBody] tag but it still won't receive any value.

Comment: So, I've created the object as suggested and it worked. But now I have a followup. I have a password property too. And somehow it deserialized the name to the password field. That's weird. I even added, in the user class, the tag (?) [JsonProperty("name")] for it to know where it's supposed to be, but it remains the same...

Comment: Could you plz provide you User Class?

Comment: Have you tried adding a 'name' property to your request object?

Comment: Oh, I see what's going on. I pasted the wrong ajax function here. This on is for the app login, thus the password, the other one has a name field instead. But it's basically the same, wth the exception that this one has 5 args and the other has 4. But still I call the function with 4 args and it still jumps for the one that has 5 args. Odd...

Comment: Ok, I got to the root of the problem. Apparently, I had two 'Ajax' named functions and I can only have one. If I have more than one he simply overwrites it. Didn't know this. Somebody just explained it to me. I'm used to c#, in which you can do that. Anyway, good answer.I ended up having problems but didn't specify, so you're good. Thanks. :)